# Concatenate strings within different arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray

I have two arrays :-

1st array has list of first names as follows :-

```
 NSArray *first = @[@"John",@"Brock",@"Taylor"];
```

And 2nd array is :-

```
 NSArray *last = @[@"Bradshaw",@"elfy",@"Swift"];
```

Now i nee a full name array.

How to concatenate strings within arrays??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `stringWithFormat`

```
   NSMutableArray *fullName = [NSMutableArray new];

    for(int i=0;i<first.count;i++)
    {
      [fullName addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",first[i],last[i]];
    }
```

Comment: Yeah looks good; however use the size of the array instead of `3` and check `first.count == last.count` as well.

Comment: Yes, but we have to keep something for @ammy also

Comment: @LalitKumar - Thanks buddy

Answer (score 2):

Try this way.

```
for(int i=0;i<first.count;i++)
{
     NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[first objectAtIndex:i],[last objectAtIndex:i]]);
}
```